# Angular Form Validation error : form is undefined

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I am trying to validate my data for a student object with Angular Form Validation, but when I want to use or print for example, the serialNumber of a student it gives me this error: Cannot read property 'serialNumber' of undefined.
Here is the code:

```html
<div *ngIf="student">
  <div class=container>
    <h2>Student {{student.name}} details</h2>
    <form name="studentForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
      <!--<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : studentForm.serialNumber.$invalid && !studentForm.serialNumber.t">-->

        <label>Serial number: {{student.serialNumber}} </label>
        <input type="text" name="serialNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="student.serialNumber" required>

        <div ng-messages="studentForm.serialNumber.$error">
          {{studentForm.serialNumber}}
            <p ng-message="required">Your name is required!</p>
        </div>
      <!--</div>-->
      <div>
        <label>Name: {{student.name}}</label>
        <input ng-model="student.name" placeholder="name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Group number: {{student.groupNumber}}</label>
        <input ng-model="student.groupNumber" placeholder="groupNumber">
      </div>

      <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
      <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't valid Angular code - thats your problem. Check out ReactiveForms and use FormBuilder to define your `studentForm` in your TS logic

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42157675/4911842). It may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-messages` and `ng-model` attribute directives do not exist in Angular 2+. I would recommend reading into [Angular Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html), [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html), and [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html).

If you would like to dual data-bind the input values, you can do so with the following syntax: `[(ngModel)]="student.serialNumber"`. However, in Angular 2+, there are usually better ways of getting values other than explicitly data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Form Validation template Driven Model

```js
  onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
    
      console.log(form);
        
  }
```

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" 
                [ngClass]="{'was-validated': form.invalid && (form.dirty || form.touched)}">
                <div class="" ngModelGroup="User">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Registration page</h2>
                    <br />                 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required
                            ngModel #firstname="ngModel">
                        <span class="help-bpx" *ngIf="firstname.touched && !firstname.valid ">Please enter the
                            firstname</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required ngModel
                            #lastname="ngModel">
                        <span class="help-bpx" *ngIf="lastname.touched && !lastname.valid ">Please enter the
                            lastname</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" email
                            required ngModel #email="ngModel">
                        <span class="help-bpx" *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid ">Please enter the Email
                            Value</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" required ngModel name="file" #file="ngModel">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <br />
                    <div class="align-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```